# Match first occurrence from back in regex

Tags: java, regex

I have to match strings between "JJ." and the second occurrence of "," from back.

e.g:

```
In Mackintosh v. Watkins (1904) 1 C L J 31, Brett and Mookerjee, JJ.
```

desired output: `Brett and Mookerjee`

Currently what i am using matches the first "," to the JJ.

my pattern:

```
",.*.[^,]*JJ\b"
```

Comment: Show the code you have tried!

Comment: Than the output should be `Brett and Mookerjee,` right ?

Comment: Is it not a sub string between `,` and `,` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use look arounds or capturing groups.

- Look ahead solution

  ```
  (?<=, )[^,]*(?=,[^,]*JJ\b)
  ```

  - `(?<=, )` Look behind, checks if the string is preceded by a `,`
  - `(?=,[^,]*JJ\b)` Look ahead. Checks if the string is followed by `,` and then anything other than `,`  and `JJ`

  [**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/zG9kE1/1)
- Capturing goups

  ```
  ,([^,]*),[^,]*JJ\b
  ```

  [**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/zG9kE1/2)

  Here the capturing group 1 will contain the string `Brett and Mookerjee`

Comment: OP wants : `"JJ." and the second occurence of "," from back` and he is doing `first "," to the JJ` . Isn't it exactly the same?

Comment: @joeyrohan Not necessarily, the negated character class `[^,]*` ensures the `,` from the back.

Answer (score 0):

Use capturing groups.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(",\\s*([^,]+),[^,]*\\bJJ\\b").matcher(s);
if(m.find())
{
System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oE1mZ5/1)